# Pattern syntax in expression

Tags: haskell, monads

I am wondering why am i getting this error since i have not used any pattern.In my case i have not pattern matched on the `filterM`'s `lambda`.

**Error**

```
 Pattern syntax in expression context: x -> not (x `elem` [".", ".."])
   |
20 |     filterFiles =filterM (x->not (x `elem` [".",".."]))
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I just want to filter the files in a given directory

**Code**

```
  module Fil where

    import System.Directory
    import Control.Monad(filterM)

    getFiles::FilePath->IO [String]
    getFiles  = getDirectoryContents

    filterFiles::[String]->IO [String]
    filterFiles =filterM (x-> not ( x `elem` [".",".."]))
```

Comment: Why does `filterFiles` have `IO [String]` as its return type? You are just filtering a plain list of strings; there's no I/O involved in the definition other than the fact that you are unnecessarily using `filterM`.

Comment: You can simply use `fmap`/`<$>` to use a function of type `[String] -> [String]` with `getFiles`: `filterFiles <$> getFiles somePath`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to include the lambda.

```
filterFiles =filterM (\x-> not ( x `elem` [".",".."]))
                      ^ here
```

Comment: You are right but now i see that i still have to add a `return` inside the lambda : 
   `filterM(\x-> return . not $ (x ``elem`` [".",".."]) `. ( unrelated to the original question anyway)

Answer (score 4):

The function `filterFiles` does not involves `IO`, use `filter` may be suitable as:

```
filterFiles::[String]->[String]
filterFiles = filter (\x-> not ( x `elem` [".",".."]))
```

Otherwise, instead of using lambda expression, using `flip` and `notElem` may be more concise as:

```
filterFiles = filter (flip notElem [".",".."])
```